# One of the buttons doesn't seem to be aligned with the others

Tags: javascript, html, css

The "Clear" button doesn't seem to be aligned with the other two buttons.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var totalStories = 3;
    var currentStory = null;
    var storyContainer = document.getElementById('story-container');
    var contentWrapper = document.getElementById('content-wrapper');

    function clearStoryContainer() {
        if (storyContainer) {
            storyContainer.style.display = 'none';
            var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
            if (generatedTextElement) {
                generatedTextElement.innerHTML = '';
            }
            if (contentWrapper) {
                contentWrapper.style.marginTop = '0px';
            }
            currentStory = null;
        }
    }

    function fetchStory(storyNumber) {
        clearStoryContainer();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'fetch.php?story=' + storyNumber, true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                if (storyContainer) {
                    storyContainer.style.display = 'block';
                    var generatedText = xhr.responseText;
                    var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
                    if (generatedTextElement) {
                        generatedTextElement.innerHTML = parseAndStyleTitles(generatedText);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Generated text element not found.');
                    }
                    if (contentWrapper) {
                        contentWrapper.style.marginTop = '0';
                    }
                    currentStory = storyNumber;
                } else {
                    console.log('Story container element not found.');
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Error fetching story. Status code: ' + xhr.status);
                clearStoryContainer();
                displayErrorMessage('Error fetching story.');
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            console.log('Network error while fetching story.');
            clearStoryContainer();
            displayErrorMessage('Network error while fetching story.');
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

    function displayErrorMessage(errorMessage) {
        if (storyContainer) {
            storyContainer.style.display = 'block';
        }
        var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
        if (generatedTextElement) {
            generatedTextElement.innerHTML = errorMessage;
        }
        if (contentWrapper) {
            contentWrapper.style.marginTop = '60px';
        }
        currentStory = null;
    }

    function parseAndStyleTitles(text) {
        return text.replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g, function (match, title) {
            return '<span>' + title + '</span>';
        });
    }

    document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var storyNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('story-number').value);

        if (!isNaN(storyNumber) && storyNumber >= 1 && storyNumber <= totalStories) {
            fetchStory(storyNumber);
            document.getElementById('story-number').value = ''; // Clear the input text
        } else {
            displayErrorMessage('Please enter a valid number between 1 and ' + totalStories + '.');
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('getRandom').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var randomStoryNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalStories) + 1;
        fetchStory(randomStoryNumber);
        document.getElementById('story-number').value = ''; // Clear the input text
    });

    document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function () {
        clearStoryContainer();
    });
});
```

```css
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        header {
            background-color: #ff6600;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 28px;
            margin: 0;
        }

        main {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #content-wrapper {
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            padding: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 1000px; /* Adjust this value to fit your screen */
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            max-height: 100%;
        }

        #story-number {
            padding: 10px 16px;
            font-size: 14px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        #get-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #get,
        #getRandom,
        #clear {
            background-color: #ff6600;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 4px;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            outline: none;
        }

        #story-container {
            background-color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            max-height: 300px; /* Set the maximum height here */
            overflow-y: auto; /* Add this line for the vertical scrollbar */
            padding: 0 20px; /* Add padding to the left and right */
        }


        #generated-text {
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 1.5;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            color: #333;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #generated-text span {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        #clear {
            display: block;
            margin: 10px auto;
        }

        @media (min-width: 601px) {
            #content-wrapper {
                max-width: 600px;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 600px) {
          #content-wrapper {
            max-width: 90%; /* Adjust width as needed */
            max-height: 80vh; /* Adjust height as needed */
            overflow-y: auto; /* Add vertical scrollbar */
          }

          #story-container {
                 max-height: 58vh; /* Adjust the value as needed for your device */
             }
          
          #get,
          #getRandom,
          #clear {
            font-size: 10px !important;
            padding: 20px 20px !important;
          }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Story Fetcher</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
      <h1>Stories</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="get-container">
          <input type="text" id="story-number" placeholder="Enter story number">
          <button id="get" type="button">Get Story</button>
          <button id="getRandom" type="button">Random Story</button>
        </div>
        <div id="story-container">
          <!-- Story content will be displayed here -->
          <div id="generated-text"></div>
          <button id="clear">Clear</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When running the code snippet everything looks fine, but in my browser (tested Google Chrome, Brave and Microsoft Edge) it looks like this: https://imageupload.io/4quysz6z76jhBAt

I've tried my best to pinpoint the issue, without any success. So I have no clue about where the error is.

Comment: all those three browsers are the same pig with different lipsticks ... it's like saying a red, green and blue toyota camry are somehow different cars

Comment: _"When running the code snippet everything looks fine"_ - because it doesn't load any actual content ... so there is no _scrollbar_ required in that section where you put the button.

Comment: Well it does load content for me, and the "Clear" button appears more to the left then the other 2 buttons, which is why I provided a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: on one browser ... anyway, CBroe's comment identifies your issue - the scroll bar

Comment: This is how it looks in Chrome: https://imageupload.io/lrR7NlUOimDy1Cw
And here's in Edge: https://imageupload.io/G0cX9k5lyCYbfd7
To me it looks the same in all 3 browsers.

Comment: because they're all the same toyota camry with different coloured paint!!! But other browsers will be the same ... BECAUSE OF THE SCROLL BAR

Comment: Yes, the buttons has the same color, I know that. So it's the scroll-bar that causes the "Clear" button to move more to the left? Do I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> it's the scroll-bar that causes the "Clear" button to move more to the
> left

...yes, in fact it causes the entire `story-container` to move to the left to accomodate the scrollbar, including the button within it.

One solution could be to move the "Clear" button outside the story container. It means you need a bit of extra JavaScript and CSS code to show and hide it at the right times, but that's not a big deal.

Demo  (just using some random endpoint data) :

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var totalStories = 3;
  var currentStory = null;
  var storyContainer = document.getElementById('story-container');

  function clearStoryContainer() {
    if (storyContainer) {
      storyContainer.style.display = 'none';
      var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
      if (generatedTextElement) {
        generatedTextElement.innerHTML = '';
      }
      var contentWrapper = document.getElementById('content-wrapper');
      currentStory = null;
    }
    document.getElementById('clear').style["display"] = "none";
  }

  function fetchStory(storyNumber) {
    var stories = [
      "652693d954105e766fc0db36",
      "652693f854105e766fc0db42",
      "652694190574da7622b775e1"
    ];
    //clearStoryContainer();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/' + stories[storyNumber - 1], true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        if (storyContainer) {
          storyContainer.style.display = 'block';
          var generatedText = xhr.responseText;
          var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
          if (generatedTextElement) {
            generatedTextElement.innerHTML = parseAndStyleTitles(generatedText);
          } else {
            console.log('Generated text element not found.');
          }
          currentStory = storyNumber;
        } else {
          console.log('Story container element not found.');
        }
        document.getElementById('clear').style["display"] = "block";
      } else {
        console.log('Error fetching story. Status code: ' + xhr.status);
        clearStoryContainer();
        displayErrorMessage('Error fetching story.');
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      console.log('Network error while fetching story.');
      clearStoryContainer();
      displayErrorMessage('Network error while fetching story.');
    };
    xhr.send();
  }

  function displayErrorMessage(errorMessage) {
    if (storyContainer) {
      storyContainer.style.display = 'block';
    }
    var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
    if (generatedTextElement) {
      generatedTextElement.innerHTML = errorMessage;
    }
    currentStory = null;
  }

  function parseAndStyleTitles(text) {
    return text.replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g, function(match, title) {
      return '<span>' + title + '</span>';
    });
  }

  document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var storyNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('story-number').value);

    if (!isNaN(storyNumber) && storyNumber >= 1 && storyNumber <= totalStories) {
      fetchStory(storyNumber);
    } else {
      displayErrorMessage('Please enter a valid number between 1 and ' + totalStories + '.');
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('getRandom').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var randomStoryNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalStories) + 1;
    fetchStory(randomStoryNumber);
  });

  document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
    clearStoryContainer();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #ff6600;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content-wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  /* Adjust this value to fit your screen */
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#story-number {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#get-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#get,
#getRandom,
#clear {
  background-color: #ff6600;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline: none;
}

#story-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  max-height: 200px;
  /* Set the maximum height here */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Add this line for the vertical scrollbar */
  padding: 0 20px;
  /* Add padding to the left and right */
}

#generated-text {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

#generated-text span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#clear {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

@media (min-width: 601px) {
  #content-wrapper {
    max-width: 600px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #content-wrapper {
    max-width: 90%;
    /* Adjust width as needed */
    max-height: 80vh;
    /* Adjust height as needed */
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* Add vertical scrollbar */
  }
  #story-container {
    max-height: 58vh;
    /* Adjust the value as needed for your device */
  }
  #get,
  #getRandom,
  #clear {
    font-size: 10px !important;
    padding: 20px 20px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Stories</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="get-container">
      <input type="text" id="story-number" placeholder="Enter story number">
      <button id="get" type="button">Get Story</button>
      <button id="getRandom" type="button">Random Story</button>
    </div>
    <div id="story-container">
      <!-- Story content will be displayed here -->
      <div id="generated-text"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Oh ok, I see. I really want it in the story container because I want to be able to press it when I've scrolled to the bottom of the page, so I guess I'll have to live with it, unless there's a work-around to force it more to the right.

Comment: `because I want to be able to press it when I've scrolled to the bottom of the page`...well you can still do that, this solution isn't stopping you, because the button is below the scrollable area anyway.

Comment: `unless there's a work-around to force it more to the right`...you could add a small left-margin to the button to compensate for the width of the scrollbar, if you want to leave it within the container. The problem with that though is that [scroll bars aren't always the same width in every browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793376/are-scroll-bars-always-the-same-width-in-different-browsers).